# iPhone simulator buttons don't respond

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, ios-4.2

Whenever I build an app on the simulator none of my buttons respond to clicks. I code the methods in the AppNameViewController files (both the header and the obj-c) I have the button connected to the File's Owner and the method selected in Interface Builder as well. Even in a simple app such as a hello world app the buttons don't do anything. Has anyone else had this problem? Any help would be much appreciated as I haven't paid for a developer license yet so the simulator is the only means I have of testing apps

Comment: dude did you connect the functions or the UIButtons to files owner

Comment: What type of buttons are? (RoundRect) is the button making blue background when tap on it?

Comment: @robin yes. @Terente they are roundrect and yes, the button turns blue when its clicked

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues before...

Try swiping across the button; for some odd reason -- sometimes, some buttons can only be activated this way in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete and reconnect the IBAction/IBOutlet.

Comment: i tried running the same code on another mac and it works fine. something must be wrong with my install. i'll try removing the devtools and reinstalling them

Comment: Do an Reset Content and Settings on your simulator.